# How to Query multiple types that has the same field but different boosts in Elasticsearch?

Tags: jquery, search, elasticsearch

I have 3 types : `[place, doctor, article]` where each type has a field named `title`. `article` type has an extra field named `body`. I want to match a query against these 3 types title fields with different boost numbers. for example : doctor's title has boost of 3 whereas place's title has boost of 2.

How can I implement this Query?(I just want the request body )

Answer (score 1):

Specific to the use case one way to achieve this is using [function_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#_using_function_score) .

You match on title and provide the boost per individual type.
The example query would be something on these lines :

```
{
    "query" : {
        "function_score" : {
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "title" : "Lucky Jim"
                }
            },
            "functions" : [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "type" : {
                            "value" : "doctor"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor" :  3
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "type" : {
                            "value" : "place"
                        }
                    },
                    "boost_factor" :  2
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "first",
            "boost_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

Note for ***elasticsearch 1.4*** onwards as per the documentation ***boost_factor*** in functions is deprecated and should be replaced by ***weight***.